# TWRP won't select USB drive with USB OTG cable

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, storage, usb-on-the-go, usb-c

I have a USB OTG type C cable with a flash drive connected to it. The flash drive is formatted with FAT32. The phone can see it, TWRP can see it, but TWRP can't select it. In TWRP I try to mount it but when I press the option it doesn't get selected. It says "(OMB)" beside the option, but there's several GB of space available. I have an SD card that can be selected fine. I'm running TWRP 3.3.1 on LineageOS.

How can I chose to make a backup to the flash drive over USB OTG?

Comment: https://www.joom.com/en/products/5b2b0c1d8b2c37010cfa6b15

Comment: Many USB-C hubs do not need external power to work because they draw power from the computer they are connected to. However, this may mean that it will not be able to power some devices that require more power than the hub can provide.